# Placing UIImage jacks up memory

Tags: iphone, memory, core-graphics, cgimage

Simply adding a UIImage with this code, makes the memory jump around 50MB. The image itself is {2448, 3264} pixels in size:

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    if (iref)
    {
        UIImage *selectedBackground = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[rep scale] orientation:(UIImageOrientation)[rep orientation]];
        CGImageRelease(iref);
        [self setBackgroundWithImage:selectedBackground orColor:nil];

    }
};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Can't get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetslibrary assetForURL:photoURL resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
```

Why the huge jump in memory?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am interested in finding a solution too.